# Creating grid-like view where the items position in the grid are fixed in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to recreate the BlockPuzzle app with SwiftUI. I am having trouble trying create the game pieces square's to have a fixed position with VStacks and HStacks. I want to show a view conditionally but if the view isn't shown then the positions of each view are changed due to swiftUIs adaptive positioning. Does anyone know I can achieve this?

I want to create this:
[how I want the game pieces to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3XMG.jpg)

This is what I saying how the square's move:
[my version of the pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7rrL.png)

If you look at my version the middle piece at the bottom section has one block is moved to the middle by swiftUI but I want it to stay aligned with the first column.

Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(model, id: \.self) { row in
            HStack {
                ForEach(row, id: \.self) { block in
                    if block == false {
                        EmptyView()
                    } else {
                        BlockView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

model is a 2D array of arrays of booleans. I'm guessing the condition of false is where I am trying to fix.

Comment: Do you have a frame set for EmptyView?

Comment: Maybe adding a Spacer() after the second ForEach() fixes the issue